# foreach loop updating matrix after each iteration R

Tags: r, loops, matrix, foreach, parallel-processing

I have a `for` loop which I want to run in parallel, so I am using `foreach` to do this.

One of the outputs from my loop, is a matrix with results from all iterations. If I use a `for` loop, then this matrix is sequentially updated, and it can be output at the end. However, when using `foreach`, it cannot seem to update this.

For example, I have put together a simple example which illustrates my point.

```
# foreach example - does not update DF matrix.
cl=makeCluster(4)
registerDoParallel(cl)
DF=matrix(NA,ncol=5,nrow=10)
foreach(i=1:10) %dopar% {
  DF[i,1]=i*1
  DF[i,2]=i*2
  DF[i,3]=i*3
  DF[i,4]=i*4
  DF[i,5]=i*5
}

# for loop - Updates DF and produces complete output.
DF=matrix(NA,ncol=5,nrow=10)
for(i in 1:10) {
  DF[i,1]=i*1
  DF[i,2]=i*2
  DF[i,3]=i*3
  DF[i,4]=i*4
  DF[i,5]=i*5
}
```

I have a feeling that I may need to specify the `DF` data frame in the `foreach` command, like I would need to do with any packages which are used, (such as `foreach(i=1:10,DF)`, but I have not managed to make this work.

Answer (score 1):

There is an option to combine your results in foreach loop. You can use that. Ideally you will need two for loops to populate a matrix. For example,

```
x <- foreach(i=1:10,.combine = rbind) %do% {
    foreach(j=1:10,.combine=c)%do%{
         j
    }
}
```

This will create a matrix. Hope this helps to get an idea

Comment: This gives me an idea of creating a matrix, however my original code requires 3 data frames be output, not just one. Therefore, I think it'd be difficult/impossible to make this work.

Comment: In that case try to vectorize your code by using `lapply` or `mclappy` if you want to run in parallel. Even if u manage to do it in `for` loop, such long for loops will be very slow in R.